# Is there a better way to update tableview model in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5, pyside

I have a table with 6 columns which are populated by 4 different datasets. Column 1 and 3 are updated 10 times per second, column 2 is a static column updated once at initalisation and then never again. The other columns are updated less frequently. I am suffering from a bit of lag - not terrible but definitely noticeable.

To update the data I am using `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel`. From the documentation I understand this will clear the table and then call data for every visible (row, column). I am updating a lot of data I don't need to.

Is there a way I can specify which columns I am changing in my update functions? Is it possible to update column2 once only and then never again?

A simplified model is shown below, in reality the data structures are different and the indexing is more complicated for some columns

```
class TableModel(PyQt5.QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, specs, length = 100000, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.default_length = length

        self.initData()
        

    def rowCount(self, parent=PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.default_length

    def columnCount(self, parent=PyQt5.QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 6

        
    def update_d1(self, dat1):
        #changes data in column 1 and 3
        #data updates 10x per second
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.dat1 = dat1
        self.endResetModel()

    def update_d2(self, middle):
        #changes data in column 2
        #data updates once on initialisation, column doesnt change thereafter
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.middle = middle
        self.endResetModel()

    def update_d3(self, dat3):
        #changes data in column 5
        #data updates twice every second
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.dat3 = dat3
        self.endResetModel()

    def update_d4(self, dat4):
        #changes column 0 and 4
        # data updates sporadically
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.col0 = dat4['col0']
        self.col4 = dat4['col4']
        self.endResetModel()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        
        if role == PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if index.row() < 0 or index.row() >= self.default_length:
                return None
            if index.column() == 0:
                val = self.col0[index.row()]
                return val

            if index.column() == 4:
                val = self.col4[index.row()]
                return val

            if index.column() == 2:
                return self.middle[index.row()]
            if index.column() == 1:
                val = self.dat1['col1'][index.row()]
                return val

            if index.column() == 3:
                val = self.dat1['col3'][index.row()]
                return val

            if index.column() == 5:
                #print(self.volume_profile)
                val = self.dat3[index.row()]
                return val
```

**EDIT**

If I change to the below it will update only the 100th row in the first column.

```
def update_d1(self, dat1):
    col1_start_index = self.index(100, 0)
    col1_end_index = self.index(100, 0)
    self.data = data
    self.dataChanged.emit(col1_start_index, col1_end_index)
```

If I set the end index to the 101st row the whole table updates again rather than just 2 cells. What is the purpose of providing two indexes?

```
def update_d1(self, dat1):
    col1_start_index = self.index(100, 0)
    col1_end_index = self.index(101, 0)
    self.data = data
    self.dataChanged.emit(col1_start_index, col1_end_index)
```

Comment: If you're just updating data, and the model size doesn't change, why are you using `beingResetModel` to begin with? You've read the documentation about it, and it's clear that that function is *not* what you need, haven't you thought about reading the *rest* of the documentation looking for what you need?

Comment: Thanks musica, see my edit for dataChanged.

Comment: That's the default behavior of all item views: whenever the topLeft and bottomRight indexes don't match, the view gets a *full* update (see [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView11dataChangedERK11QModelIndexS2_RK7QVectorIiE). A possible workaround could be to create a custom signal for the model and connect it to a function that only updates the indexes in the range.

Comment: Would a custom signal be equivalent in efficiency to looping through the start and end indices and emiting dataChanged for each?

Comment: Theoretically not: that only depends on how you're emitting those signals. If they are emitted within the same event loop (simplifying, the `dataChange` signals are all sent from the same function call, including any recursion level) it won't change *that much*: the result is that the view will schedule an update for each `visualRect` of the dataChanged indexes. You could try to do some level of optimization by "grouping" all changed indexes and emit a signal with those indexes, then in the connected view function create a QRegion that contains all those index rects using `visualRect`.

Comment: But this is just a speculation: I don't know how Qt actually behaves with complex region updates (especially for item views): AFAIK if a QRegion contains multiple rectangles it only updates those rectangles, not the "bounding rectangle" that contains all of them, but I cannot tell you that I'm 100% sure that **only** those rectangles will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be emitting the [`dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles = QVector<int>())`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal instead. The `beginXxx` and `endXxx` APIs are for *structural* changes where the *shape* of the model changes. Since you're only changing the *contents* (or the data) of the model - do not use the structural APIs in that case.

Comment: Thanks Kuba, see my edit on the implementation of this?

Comment: This will not work unless the UI thread is the one calling the dataChanged function.  Given that the data is being updated 10x a second, I would guess some other thread is doing the updates.  Resetting the model works, however poorly.